# How are the van der waal constants 'a' and 'b' related to molecular size?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gas-laws

'a' represents the measure of attractive forces between the gas molecules so how is it related to the molecular size? if a1> a2 then what does it tell us about the molecular sizes of 1 and 2?

Comment: a is not related to molecular sizes, b is.

Comment: $a$ is included in the pressure correction term ,$b$ is included in the volume correction term. Higher value of  $a$ means more attraction and hence , lesser size.

Comment: vdW equation is just a model. While the textbook derivation of the equation may sound intuitive, 'a' and 'b' are not actual molecular parameters, just parametrization.

Answer (score 2):

The real gas equation or van der Waals’ equation of state is
$$\left(P + \frac{an^2}{V^2}\right)(V - nb) = nRT $$

where the constants a and b are known as van der Waals’ constants.

$a$ is a measure of van der waals forces of attraction existing between the molecules of a given gas. Greater the value of $a$ greater is the strength of the forces. It doesn’t affect molecular size.

On the other hand, $b$ is the incompressible volume per mole for a gas. It is directly proportional to the size of gas molecules.

Comment: Note that for example, water and ammonia have almost similar $b$, but their $a$ differs significantly. [Source](http://www2.ucdsb.on.ca/tiss/stretton/database/van_der_waals_constants.html)

Comment: But their molecular sizes are similar. So we can say $a$ doesn’t affect molecular sizes right?